# cannot build table with PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I would like for tab 2 to show a table of all existing reservations.

I have tried making the dataframe a string and then a list.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame



#create dataframe to simulate databse with names and dates
data = {'Name':  ['Joe Smith', 'Jason Leary','Bill Murray'],
        'Start Date': ['2019/10/01', '2019/11/01','2019/12/01'],
        'End Date': ['2019/10/15', '2019/11/15','2019/12/15']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Name','Start Date','End Date'])
Data_Table = df.to_string()




# Stuff inside window
tab1_layout = [
    [sg.Text('The Scheduler')], 
    [sg.Combo(name, size=(30,4), enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Combo(reason, size=(30,4), enable_events=True)],
    [sg.T('Start Date')],
          [sg.In('', size=(10,1), key='input1')],
          [sg.CalendarButton('Choose Start Date', target='input1', key='date1',format='%Y/%m/%d')],
    [sg.T('End Date')],
          [sg.In('', size=(10,1), key='input2')],
          [sg.CalendarButton('Choose End Date', target='input2', key='date2', format='%Y/%m/%d')],
    [sg.Button('Submit')]]

# create a table to show names and dates with an export to CSV button
tab2_layout = [[sg.Table(values=Data_Table, max_col_width=25, background_color='lightblue',
                        auto_size_columns=True, justification='right', alternating_row_color='blue', key='_table_')],
          [sg.Button('Update')]]



tab3_layout = [[sg.T('This is inside tab 3')],
               [sg.In(key='_in3_')]]
# create the window
layout = [[sg.TabGroup([[sg.Tab('Scheduler', tab1_layout,  key='_mykey_'),
                         sg.Tab('Schedule', tab2_layout),
                         sg.Tab('Admin', tab3_layout)]],
                         key='_group2_', title_color='darkgrey',
                         selected_title_color='black', tab_location='topleft')]]

window = sg.Window('My window with tabs', default_element_size=(30,1)).Layout(layout)

# event loop to process events and get the values of inputs
while True:      
    event, values = window.Read() 
    print(event, values)       
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):      
        break 
     if event == 'Update':
        window.FindElement('_table_').Update( row_colors=((8,'white', 'red'), (9,'black')))

window.Close()
```

I would like for a table to show on tab 2 with existing reservations. Ultimately this will come from a db but for now I have created a pd.DataFrame.

The error is 
TclError: Invalid column index
But I have tried strings and lists.

Answer (score 2):

In sg.table you need to include:

> headings = header_list

```
header_list = [str(x) for x in range(len(data[0]))] 
tab2_layout = [[sg.Table(values=Data_Table, max_col_width=25,
               background_color='lightblue',
               auto_size_columns=True,
               justification='right',alternating_row_color='blue',
               key='_table_', headings = header_list)]
               [sg.Button('Update')]]
```

For more Details See:

https://repl.it/@PySimpleGUI/Table-Element